# Bind data from database to bootstrap table in asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, database, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap for the first time. I am wondering what is the right way to bind data from the database to the control (In my case a table with in an accordion pane). 
[image: boot Strap table with in accordion pane]

I was able to achieve the desired result using bootstrap and plain html using below code.

```
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                           <table class="table">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Recieved</th>
                                        <th>Type</th>
                                        <th>File Name</th>
                                        <th>File Size</th>
                                        <th>Avg Size</th>
                                        <th># Rows</th>
                                        <th>Avg Rows</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>12/26/2018</td>
                                        <td>Hospital</td>
                                        <td>20181218_StJoseph...</td>
                                        <td>17.8 GB</td>
                                        <td>20.4 GB</td>
                                        <td>6204</td>
                                        <td>1156</td>
                                        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Clear Alert</button></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>12/19/2018</td>
                                        <td>Pharmacy</td>
                                        <td>20181218_StJoseph...</td>
                                        <td>18.0 GB</td>
                                        <td>8.0 GB</td>
                                        <td>6204</td>
                                        <td>1156</td>
                                        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Clear Alert</button></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

But I don't know how do I bind data to the table from a stored procedure. and also how can I have a button on each row when I bind data from database.

Help/Guidance is much appreciated. 
Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the data from dB and render the second  in a loop using some serverside tech such as PHP or asp.net or using some JavaScript or a JavaScript Framework such as jQuery angular etc. Will elaborate later. This is a general direction u need to take without going into too much detail.

Comment: Thanks for responding Preet. Could you please elaborate.How do I add a clear button on every row when binding data using jquery.  how should table html look like. Thanks a lot.